# Removing first array of multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I want to remove the first.. how to say that outside of the array and left inside array of a multidimension array. I couldn't found out the solution.. someone knows how to do it??
This is my code. I assign a array and i try to put into another array like this.

```
$final_sku = array();
    foreach($skus as $sku){
        foreach($sku as $key => $s){
            $final_sku[] = array('Sku' => $s);
        }
    }
    
    $newArray = array(
        "Product" => array(
            "PrimaryCategory" => "1",
            "AssociatedSku" => "12",
            "Attributes" => array(

            ),
            "Skus" => $final_sku
        )
    );
```

And this is the $final_sku output be like.

```
              [0] => Array
                    (
                        [Sku] => Array
                            (
                                [package_weight] => 5
                                [package_length] => 4
                                [package_width] => 3
                                [package_height] => 2
                                [package_content] => 
                                [tax_class] => default
                                [color_family] => Antique White
                                [price] => 4
                                [special_price] => 
                                [SellerSku] => sku1
                                [variation] => var1
                            )

                    )

                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [Sku] => Array
                            (
                                [package_weight] => 5
                                [package_length] => 4
                                [package_width] => 3
                                [package_height] => 2
                                [package_content] => 
                                [tax_class] => default
                                [color_family] => Apricot
                                [price] => 4
                                [special_price] => 
                                [SellerSku] => sku2
                                [variation] => var1
                            )

                    )
```

I want the output be like this.

```
                        [Sku] => Array
                            (
                                [package_weight] => 5
                                [package_length] => 4
                                [package_width] => 3
                                [package_height] => 2
                                [package_content] => 
                                [tax_class] => default
                                [color_family] => Antique White
                                [price] => 4
                                [special_price] => 
                                [SellerSku] => sku1
                                [variation] => var1
                            )

                 
                        [Sku] => Array
                            (
                                [package_weight] => 5
                                [package_length] => 4
                                [package_width] => 3
                                [package_height] => 2
                                [package_content] => 
                                [tax_class] => default
                                [color_family] => Apricot
                                [price] => 4
                                [special_price] => 
                                [SellerSku] => sku2
                                [variation] => var1
                            )
```

UPDATE: I want to pass the array and convert to xml. So the array key would be duplicated.

Comment: You cannot have the output as you want it, an array has to have a unique key.  `Sku` can only appear once in an array at the same level.

Comment: When I use $final_sku[0] it works but it only return one record. Any solution? Thanks

Comment: _"Any solution"_ to solve what exactly? What outcome are you looking for?

Comment: Because I want to put into xml.. so it could have duplicate array key for that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not make sense to have the same array of 2 members under the same key.
If you want to access one of them, what will be its uniqueness over the other?

The logical solution is

```
[sku] => [
           0 => [first sku data....], 
           1 => [sku data....], 

         ]
```